# Why does my "/var/app/staging" contains gem files that is absent on my current app on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-cache

I tried to connect Redis Elastic Cache to my Elastic Beanstalk environment but failed then I deleted all mentions of "Redis" from my app and then even created new environment but my `/var/app/staging` still contains `redis.rb` and cannot process it giving this error.

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `redis' for main:Object
Did you mean?  redo
/var/app/staging/config/initializers/redis.rb:1:in `<main>'
```